# In electron-photon Compton scattering should the scattered photon form a 'radiation cone'?

Tags: waves, photons, electrons, scattering

If we imagine a photon as a little bit more wave than particle should it form a cone after being scattered from a let say point particle or what ever an electron could possibly be? As the electron has not a flat surface should it scatter the photon as a wave in more than only one direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of quantum objects does not depend on whether we *think* of them as a wave or a particle. The predictions of quantum mechanics are almost always probabilities, and so it is in the case of the scattering of two quantum objects off each other.

The usual way to present the results of quantum scattering experiments is as a [differential cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)#Quantum_scattering). This is a function $\sigma(\theta,\phi)$ that tells you how likely it is that a detector positioned at an angle $\theta,\phi$ (relative to some arbitrary axis through the point of scattering) will detect the particle. This is almost exactly the same as an ordinary wavefunction - it's just a probability density for a position measurement on the scattered particle.

Correctly computing the differential cross section for electron-photon scattering was one of the early triumphs of quantum field theory in the form of the [Klein-Nishina formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Nishina_formula). Note that in particular for low energies of the incident photon, this distribution is very far from anything like a "cone" - the photon has a significant probability to just be scattered back into the direction it came from.